# Multiple filters who are optional on MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database table with the following columns:

```
ID
Foo
Bar
Gux
```

Foo can hold the values [a, b, c], Bar [1, 2, 3], and Gux [x, y, z].

In my interface I have a HTML select box to filter on Foo, Bar, and Gux. The problem is that the user can filter on one, two, or three parameters in random order.

This gives me a problem to make an efficient SQL-query and bind_param.

I could do something like this:

```
//Pseudo code

$sql = "";

if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE foo=?";
}
if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE bar=?";
}
if (isset($_GET['gux'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE gux=?";
}
```

But what if the use selected foo and bar? This would also be very ugly and hard to implement the bind_params too.

Ideal would be a wildcard so I could do

```
//Pseudo code

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE foo=* AND bar=* AND gux=*";
```

and only replace the `*` with an actual value when a filter for that column is selected. But this is not supported for integers.

Another option I thought of would be to do the following:

```
//Pseudo code

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE foo=filter1 OR bar=filter2 OR gux=filter3";
```

And to programmatically replace the `OR` with `AND` when a value for that column is selected. This also would solve the bind_param issue. But I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: build your WHERE clause seperately, adding column name and `?` for each input thats there.

Comment: As you go, for each `?` you add, place the value into an array. Then you have the means to do the binding to the right column

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nigel Ren's Answer doesn't explain on how to do the `bind_param` part. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RiggsFolly has mentioned, build the WHERE clause dynamically.  This code assumes there will be at least 1 option (otherwise add the WHERE conditionally as well.)

Each part is added to a list along with a corresponding bind array, this shows the data, you will need to add the actual API part for the database. 
 The WHERE part is put together using `implode()` with `AND` as the glue...

```
$binds = [];
$where = [];
$types = '';
if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $where[] = "foo=?";
    $binds[] = $_GET['foo'];
    $types .= "s";
}
if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
    $where[] = "bar=?";
    $binds[] = $_GET['bar'];
    $types .= "s";
}
if (isset($_GET['gux'])) {
    $where[] = "gux=?";
    $binds[] = $_GET['gux'];
    $types .= "i";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);

echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
print_r($binds);
```

with 1 in the foo value gives...

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE foo=?
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Then use the types and the binds in the `bind_param()`...

```
bind_param($types, ...$binds);
```

Comment: And how would I do the bind_param part? If I only select `foo` `bind_param` needs to be `bind_param("s", ...)` If I select only `bar` it needs to be `bind_param("i",...)`. And than I'm not talking yet about two filters selected (which can also be selected in random order).

Comment: Loop the `$binds` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly `print_r` gives this output `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 )` How am I supposed to extract the datatype (s or i) and the selected filter (Foo/bar/gux) from that? `Array([0])` for example is always filter Foo if I select Foo. But when I only select Gux `Array([0])` is the Gux filter.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe a possible solution is to set the Array-key in the if statement when appending to `binds`. But there should be a better way?

Comment: Well if datatype is what you want, store that also into the array. However recently I found that MYSQLI_ could not give a bam what datatype you use in the `bind_param()` so you could use `s` for everything

Comment: Sorry, been busy - I've added some more code to show how to use types and then put the data into `bind_param()`.